# re: Grid Issue with environmental data-frame in R

Tags: raster, r, data-frame

So I am trying to use the package ppmLasso to create species distribution models. Before I can run my models I need to put my environmental data into a data frame instead of as a raster. I have done the conversion using the following code for all the variables in the ClimateTreeStack Raster:

class       : RasterStack

dimensions  : 4746, 5858, 27802068, 6  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)

resolution  : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)

extent      : 92.19167, 141.0083, -11, 28.55  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs

names       : bio_1, bio_2, bio_3, bio_12, bio_15, Allsea1

min values  :   -45,    45,    34,    581,      5,       0

max values  :   289,   132,    96,   7008,    126,      89

> bio1_FRAME<-as.data.frame(ClimateTreeStack$bio_1, xy=TRUE)
>
> FrameOmit1<-na.omit(bio1_FRAME)
>
> X<-FrameOmit1$x
>
> Y<-FrameOmit1$y
>
> BIO_1<-FrameOmit1$bio_1*

Which yields the following data frame:

> head(frame)
>
> X        Y BIO_1 BIO_2 BIO_3 BIO_12 BIO_15 tree
>
> 1 97.55417 28.54583     8   114    44    698     85    8
>
> 2 97.56250 28.54583    -2   115    44    688     86    5
>
> 3 97.57083 28.54583    -1   115    44    688     86    1
>
> 4 97.55417 28.53750     2   115    44    692     86    4
>
> 5 97.56250 28.53750     2   115    44    692     86    5
>
> 6 97.57083 28.53750    11   114    44    703     86    4

I then try to use this environmental data frame but the ppmlasso package fails. I have figured out that an issue may be that the environmental data frame doesn't represent a true grid as seen using the diff() function:

> varX = sort(unique(frame$X))
>
> varY = sort(unique(frame$Y))
>
> X.step = diff(varX)
>
> Y.step = diff(varY)
>
> table(X.step)

X.step

0.00833333333332575 0.00833333333333997 0.00833333333335418

```
           3177                2261                 419
```

> table(Y.step)

Y.step

0.00833333333332931 0.00833333333333286 0.00833333333333464 0.00833333333333641 0.00833333333333997

```
              1                4107                 110                 457                  60
```

0.0250000000000057    0.05833333333333

```
   1                    1
```

When using the diff() function data appropriate for ppmlasso should look like this:

> BM.X = sort(unique(BlueMountains$env$X))
>
> BM.Y = sort(unique(BlueMountains$env$Y))
>
> BM.X.step = diff(BM.X)
>
> BM.Y.step = diff(BM.Y)
>
> table(BM.X.step)

BM.X.step

0.5

200

> table(BM.Y.step)

BM.Y.step

0.5

300

**So I know what my problem probably is. But I do not know how to fix it. Can someone please suggest the easiest way to coerce my data frame (or raster) so that it has equal grid cells and can be run through ppmlasso?**

Comment: Try projecting the raster to an equal-area CRS before pulling location points out, perhaps?

Comment: How exactly does the package fail?  If it indeed is due to the imprecision in some of the variables, then `signif` can be your friend.

Comment: @obrl_soil : I tried that and it worked for the X values but not the Y values....I projected it to an equal-area CRS: "+proj=aea +lat_1=7 +lat_2=-32 +lat_0=-15 +lon_0=125 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

Comment: @whuber: The process fails at the start....it just runs and runs and won't quite. I tried the `signif` but I still had the same issue.

Comment: I am a PhD student trying to use the `ppmlasso` for my dissertation so I am under a time crunch and I am getting so frustrated....So I GREATLY appreciate any help and ideas.